# How do you get the fully qualified method name when an exception happens

Tags: .net, reflection, exception

I have a global HandledExceptionHandler.  In the catch part of my try catch block I would like to pass the fully qualifed method name where the exception occurred.  How do you do that?  Can it be done without reflection.  HEre is an example of what I am looking for...

```
Public Sub MySub
   Try
      'some error happens

   Catch
      HandledException (ERROR_LOCATION, SOME_OTHER_ARGUMENT)
   End Try


End Sub
```

How do I get the ERROR_LOCATION in this case?

Seth

Answer (score 5):

If you have the exception object you can see use the [TargetSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.targetsite.aspx) property to obtain the information about where the exception was thrown.